# Getting null pointer on response when trying to mock rest template

Tags: spring, unit-testing, mockito

Im trying to mock the below rest call using mockito inside an unit test.

```
  String url = baseUrl  + "/samples";

  ResponseEntity<SampleDto> response =
                restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, SampleDto.class);
```

and its mocked using :

```
  when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(anyString()),eq(HttpMethod.GET), null,
            eq(SampleDto.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new SampleDto(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

but the `response` keeps getting null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you mock restTemplate? You can use MockMVC to imitate controller usage

Comment: This is some additional REST call that i want to mock.

Comment: Ok, so you can use WireMock for REST call [example](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock)

Comment: This is for the test case, so i dont want to use a wiremock for that. Its a fair scenario i hope, so just want to make this work

Comment: For your case problem in exchange parameters, Mockito cannot match `(eq(anyString()),eq(HttpMethod.GET), null, eq(SampleDto.class)`. If you change all parameters to `any()`, this should work.

Comment: No it doesnt work either. `when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(any()),eq(any()), null,eq(SampleDto.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new SampleDto(), HttpStatus.OK));`

`Invalid use of argument matchers!`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following configuration

```
  when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString()
                , Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET)
                , null
                , Mockito.<Class<SampleDto>>any())
   ).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(new SampleDto(), HttpStatus.OK));
```